# Custom test suite for django app

Tags: django, unit-testing, test-suite

I have a pretty complex django app which has following structure.

```
/myapp
/myapp/obj1/..
/myapp/obj1/views.py
/myapp/obj1/forms.py
/myapp/obj2/..
/myapp/obj2/views.py
/myapp/obj2/forms.py
/myapp/tests/..
/myapp/tests/__init__.py
/myapp/tests/test_obj1.py
/myapp/tests/test_obj2.py
```

I have a lot more objects. In `/myapp/tests/__init__.py` I import `TestCase` instances from `test_obj1.py` and `test_obj2.py` and it is enough to run all available test.

What I'm trying to do is to create a custom test suite. According to the documentation:

> There is a second way to define the test suite for a module: if you
>   define a function called suite() in either models.py or tests.py, the
>   Django test runner will use that function to construct the test suite
>   for that module. This follows the suggested organization for unit
>   tests. See the Python documentation for more details on how to
>   construct a complex test suite.

So, i've created this function like this:

```
def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestObj1Form())
    suite.addTest(TestObj2Form())
    return suite
```

However, when I run tests I get this error: `ValueError: no such test method in <class 'myproject.myapp.tests.test_obj1.TestObj1Form'>: runTest`. Of course I can define this method, but then if I run test it will invoke only this method and ignore all of the `test*` methods.

Any suggestions how to create a custom test suite for django app properly? I've googled and I found nothing about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add *all your tests* with a special function:

```
suite.addTest(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestObj1Form))
```